# How To Reduce Multiple Ajax Calls

Tags: html, web-services, jquery, cordova

I'm Developing A windows Phone 7 Application Using Phone Gap.Language Used[HTML,css,JavaScript]

I'm using A web Service For Get Json Data Web service And Bind In Drop Down List.

In Single Page I'M Using 5 AJAX Calls Ex[Age,Height,Religion,Cast,Country,Language,Status,Education]

My Sample Ajax Call For Age given Below.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     url: "https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/yyyyyyyy/zzzzzzzzzz.svc/GetMasterDataoverHTTPS?AuthToken=" + encodeAuthtoken + "&ListKey=" + encodeListkey + "&ListValue=" + encodeMinAge,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        var result = data;
        $.each(result, function (key, value) {
            var appenddata = "<option value = '" + value.ListKey + "'>" + value.ListValue + " </option>";
            $('#ddlSFromAge').html($('#ddlSFromAge').html() + appenddata);
        });

        //alert(result);
    },
    error: errorResponse
});

function errorResponse(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

    alert('Error on Ajax Call' + '\n Status: ' + xhr.status + '\n Response Text: ' + xhr.responseText + '\n Error: ' + thrownError);
}enter code here
```

For Each And Ever Drop Down I call Like This . I know This Is Not Good.

Any One Tell Me How To Reduce This AJAX call's [For Each Drop down Separate URL Used]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you are using so many ajax calls because the data types are dynamic? If they are not dynamic, then you should really consider using the device sqlite database to store your values and just query that. Documentation can be found [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage).

If you really really need to make that many calls because the data is dynamic then so be it. But instead of having 5 seperate AJAX functions you can just use 1 function and either pass the function your url you want it to use `function ajaxCall('http://www.myserviceurl')` or pass it a value to run agains a switch to determine what url to use.

Comment: Any Sample For Your Second Option

Comment: Will do something for you in an hour or so after lunch

Comment: Hi Dom Thank You For Your Solution And Spend Your Time For My Request. I Need Some Solution For Same Problem.

Comment: If First Time Ajax Call for Age Is run Successfully and Value Bind To **ddlSFromAge** Drop down ID. Next height web service Data Not Bind In Same **ddlFromAge** I'M using Separate Drop down For Each Web service for height my Drop down Id Is **ddlHeight** Now My Question Is How I Bind Height Web service To **ddlHeight** Id On Your Give Solution Code. Thank You

Comment: It is starting to get a bit messy and you could probably combine the switch statements but here is a quick sample for you. http://jsfiddle.net/WxMys/1/

Answer (score 0):

I Changed My Code Like This Credits Go To @Dom

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    doAjaxCall("Country");
    doAjaxCall("Language");
    doAjaxCall("religion");
    doAjaxCall("Caste");

    function doAjaxCall(type) {
        var url;
        switch (type) {
            case "Country":
                url = "https://www.xxxxxx.com/yyyyyyy/GetCountryoverHTTPS?AuthToken=Z0lFITFVMw==&FormCode=U1A=";
                ajaxCall(url, '#ddlCountry');
                break;
            case "Language":
                url = "https://www.xxxxxx.com/yyyyyyy/GetLanguageoverHTTPS?AuthToken=Z0lFITFVMw==&FormCode=U1A=";
                ajaxCall(url, '#ddlLanguage');
                break;
            case "religion":
                url = "https://www.xxxxxx.com/yyyyyyy/GetReligionoverHTTPS?AuthToken=Z0lFITFVMw==&FormCode=U1A=";
                ajaxCall(url, '#ddlReligion');
                break;
            case "Caste":
                url = "https://www.xxxxxx.com/yyyyyyy/GetMotherTongueoverHTTPS?AuthToken=Z0lFITFVMw==&FormCode=U1A=";
                ajaxCall(url, '#ddlMother');
                break;

            default:
                url = ""; //or some other code to execute if type doesnt match anything
        }
        function ajaxCall(paramurl,paramControlId) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: url,
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (data) {
                    var result = data;
                    $.each(result, function (key, value) {
                        var appenddata = "<option value = '" + value.ListKey + "'>" + value.ListValue + " </option>";
                        $(paramControlId).html($(paramControlId).html() + appenddata);
                    });

                    //alert(result);
                },
                error: errorResponse
            });
            function errorResponse(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                alert('Error on Ajax Call' + '\n Status: ' + xhr.status + '\n Response Text: ' + xhr.responseText + '\n Error: ' + thrownError);
            }
        }
    }
</script>`
```